# Reading with IFS=' ' , delimit one space but not multiple space

Tags: bash, ifs

I am trying to read string into array using space as delimiter here I don't want to break down the spaces inside single quote or I can use double quote, if I use IFS='' (null), then all the words are getting read into first index but that's not purpose.

```
x="-r asdf -w test='foo      ' "
IFS=' '  read -r -a y<<<$x
echo ${y[@]}
```

Output:
-r asdf -w test='foo ' #Spaces are gone.

Thanks.

Comment: So don't use `IFS=`. Read the whole line. And parse each character in the whole line manually.

Comment: then whole sentence is reading into first index of variable.

Comment: I do not understand your comment. What "sentence"? How a [sentence](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/sentence_1) can do an action, ie. "read"? `I don't want to break down the spaces inside single quote or I can use double quote` Exactly - write your own parser that will handle that.

Comment: Sorry for my wording, my point is the entire string was read into first element of array, If I remove IFS, > x="-r asdf -w test='foo      '"
> read -r -a y<<<$x
> echo ${y[@]}
-r asdf -w test='foo      '
> echo ${y[0]}
-r asdf -w test='foo      '
> echo ${y[1]}

Comment: you can't use quotes inside a string, they have no worth and treated as literally characters

Comment: thats the purpose need those quotes